# Autostarting Python scripts on boot using crontab on rasbian

Tags: python, cron, reboot

I am a pretty new python programmer and am a little bit familiar with crontab. What I am trying to do is probably not the best practice but it is what I am most familiar with.

I have a raspberry pi with a couple python scripts I want to run on boot and stay running in the background. They are infinite loop programs. They are tested and working in a cmd terminal and have been function for a couple weeks. Just getting tired on manually starting them up. When the pi goes through a power cycle.

So I did a `sudo crontab -e` and added this line as my only entry

`@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/script.py &`

If I copy paste this exactly (minus the @reboot) it will run successfully in the cmd line.

I am using a cmd:
`pgrep -af python`to check to see if it is running. I normally see two scripts running there but not the one I am trying to add.

I am not sure where I am going wrong or my best method to troubleshoot my issue. From the research I have been doing it seems like it should work.

Thanks for your help
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it easier to create a systemd service file for each program that you want to start when you Raspberry Pi boots. systemd comes with a few more tools to help you debug your configuration.

This is what an example systemd service file (located at `/etc/systemd/system/myscript.service`) would look like:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/script.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/myscript
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and then you can enable this program to run on boot with the command:

```
sudo systemctl enable myscript.service
```

These examples are from [Raspberry Pi's documentation about systemd](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md). But because systemd is widely used in the Linux world, so you can also follow documentation and StackOverflow answers for other Linux distributions.

Comment: You are right. This is much easier and much better ! Thank you for your help it is now working as intended.

If i wanted to run a python script that is NOT an infinite loop. is there a way I could have it automatically run again everytime it finishes?

Comment: @KevinLay, glad to hear my answer helped. If your program runs as an infinite loop, then you create a systemd "service" as I described above. If you want to repeatedly rerun a program that ends, then you create a systemd "timer." [Here is an article](https://opensource.com/article/20/7/systemd-timers) that introduces systemd timers.